# Django User Creation without Form

Tags: python, django

I am building an analytics platform for our app.

To create users who can access the analytics platform I am choosing existing user's from our app that do no utilize djangos user model. I then plan to create a django user for the selected user so I can use djangos built in authentication.

I have seen many examples of creating django users with a form, but instead of writing an email into a textbox I am choosing an existing user on our app from a search list.

Because of this I don't think I can utilize a form and am wondering how I should go about creating a user?

I was planning on sending the user I selected's id and the password to the view that would create the user with AJAX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just call the [create_user()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) method:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User.objects.create_user(username='somename', password='somepass')
```